# Почему в Symfony 2 возникает ошибка при работе с каскадом?

Tags: symfony4

Доброе время суток всем, подскажите почему может возникать ошибка?

Я использую вот этот код:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$do = $this->getDoctrine();
/** @var ContentBlock $ContentBlocks */
/** @var ContentBlockArchive $ContentBlocksArchive */
$ContentBlocksArchive = new ContentBlockArchive();
$ContentBlockContent = $do->getRepository(ContentBlockContent::class)->findOneBy(array('block_id'=>$ContentBlocks->getId()));
$lang = $ContentBlockContent->getAliasId();
$type = $do->getRepository(ContentBlockType::class)->findOneBy(array('type'=>$ContentBlocks->getType()));
$ContentBlocksArchive->setType($type);
$ContentBlocksArchive->setValue($ContentBlockContent->getValue());
$ContentBlocksArchive->setLang($lang->getAlias());
$ContentBlocksArchive->setAlias($ContentBlocks->getAlias());
$ContentBlocksArchive->setName($ContentBlocks->getName());
$ContentBlocksArchive->setTimeAdd();
$em->persist($ContentBlocksArchive);
$em->flush();
```

При его работе возникает ошибка:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\ContentBlockContent#block_id' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: 
App\Entity\ContentBlock@0000000052faa8f9000000000c55abc4. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\ContentBlock#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

Подскажите из за чего может возникать подобная ошибка не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

В App\Entity\ContentBlockContent создается новая связанная по 'block_id' запись, но для нее не выполняется persist и не настроены каскадные действия. Надо связи смотреть.